# Using sqlite3 with C . Failed to execute statement ! database is locked

Tags: c, sqlite, error-handling

I'm trying to insert users into a database and after the first call I receive the error 'database is locked' despite using sqlite3_free.I can't find where the issue is.Tried to sqlite3_free() on different variables linked to handling the database and still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
Here is the code:

```
int signup_procedure(char *rcv_string)
{
    printf("[server]: Sign up procedure started\n");
    //aici fac signup si insert in baza de date
    char name[20],pass[20];
    char string[100];
    strcpy(string,rcv_string);
    char *token;
    token = strtok(string," ");
    strcpy(name,token);
    token = strtok(NULL," ");
    strcpy(pass,token);
    printf("[server]: User name: %s\n",name);
    printf("[server]: User password: %s\n",pass);
    sqlite3 * datab;
    sqlite3_stmt * res;
    int rec = 0;
    char *db_err=0;
    rec = sqlite3_open("users.db",&datab);
    if(rec != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        printf("[database]: Failed to open database ! %s \n", sqlite3_errmsg(datab));
        sqlite3_close(datab);
        return errno;
    }
    //check if user already exists
    
    char *sql = "SELECT id FROM USER WHERE name = @name";
    rec = sqlite3_prepare_v2(datab, sql, -1, &res, 0);
    if(rec == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        int idx = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(res, "@name");
        sqlite3_bind_text(res, idx, name, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    } else {

        printf("[database]: Failed to execute statement ! %s \n", sqlite3_errmsg(datab));
    }
    int step = sqlite3_step(res);
    char id[5]="0";
    if(step == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        
        strcpy(id,sqlite3_column_text(res,0));
        printf("[database]: User already exists with the id %s \n", id);
    }
    else{
        //incep procedura de insert
        printf("[server]: User does not exists in the database and will be registred.\n");
        char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO USER (name,pass) VALUES ('%q','%q');",name,pass);
        printf("[server]: SQL statement: %s\n",sql);
        rec = sqlite3_exec(datab, sql, NULL, NULL, &db_err);
        if(rec != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            printf("[database]: Failed to execute statement ! %s \n", sqlite3_errmsg(datab));
            sqlite3_free(NULL);
            sqlite3_close(datab);
            return errno;
        }   else{
            printf("[database]: User registred successfully\n");
            sqlite3_free(NULL);
        }
       /* rec = sqlite3_prepare_v2(datab, sql, -1, &res, 0);
        if(rec == SQLITE_OK)
        {
        } else {

            printf("[database]: Failed to execute statement ! %s \n", sqlite3_errmsg(datab));
        }*/
    }
    printf("[server]: Sign up successful\n");
}
 int main()
 {
     signup_procedure("test3 test3");
     signup_procedure("test2 test4");
 }
```

Here's the terminal output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOoJm.png)

Comment: You're not finalizing the prepared statement, or closing the database on function exit.

Comment: (it's better to open the database once and use that throughout the life of your program than repeatedly open and close one)

Comment: Deleted all the sqlite3_close but the error is still persisting. The error seems to appear only in this case: 
-calling the function with an user that already exists 
-calling the function again with an user that does not exist.
I can't seem to find the problem in my code.

Comment: You shouldn't *remove* the existing close calls unless you restructure things to follow the suggestion about only opening the db once and reusing that connection.